# MongoDB With nested $in and $or

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using the MongoDB PHP Library and have the following query array

```
Array
(
  [$and] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
          [$or] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
                (
                  [role.name] => Array
                    (
                      [$in] => Array
                        (
                          [0] => 'User'
                          [1] => 'VIP User'
                        )
                    )
                )
              [1] => Array
                (
                  [role._id] => Array
                    (
                      [$in] => Array
                        (
                          [0] => 'User'
                          [1] => 'VIP User'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Which does not work. However, this does:

```
Array
(
  [$and] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
          [role.name] => Array
            (
              [$in] => Array
                (
                  [0] => 'User'
                  [1] => 'VIP User'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Any idea what the problem is? (This is an abstracted example)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've been trying but I don't even know the basic syntax for the shell. Besides, I normally have issues translating shell examples to PHP.

Comment: Well, I personally have difficulties translating PHP var dumps to something meaningful. Too much visual noise :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Do you know if it's even possible to put $in statements in an $or statement?

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well I know Mongo has had some weird restrictions in the past, and I'm pretty new to it. To me, my syntax looks right so I was starting to think it wasn't possible. I've tried a bunch of variations of my query too

Comment: One hint, though: you don't need outermost `$and`. top level conditions are `and`-ed by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your queries, apart from the redundant `$and` operator. Consider the following Mongo shell example:

```
> db.foo.drop()
true
> db.foo.insert({role:{name:"User"}});
> db.foo.insert({role:{name:"Admin"}});
> db.foo.insert({role:{name:"VIP User"}});
> db.foo.find({$or:[{"role.name":{$in:["User", "VIP User"]}}, {"role._id":{$in:["User", "VIP User"]}}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fea16dcdb49621e28c004a2"), "role" : { "name" : "User" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fea16e8db49621e28c004a4"), "role" : { "name" : "VIP User" } }
> db.foo.find({$and:[{$or:[{"role.name":{$in:["User", "VIP User"]}}, {"role._id":{$in:["User", "VIP User"]}}]}]});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fea16dcdb49621e28c004a2"), "role" : { "name" : "User" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fea16e8db49621e28c004a4"), "role" : { "name" : "VIP User" } }
```

Note that there isn't a `role._id` field in my data, so it was simply ignored.

If you're having trouble with the JavaScript shell, it may be helpful to walk through the examples in the [$or and $and](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) documentation. Both operators expect an array as their value, which in turn can contain any number of valid criteria objects.

The main benefit of `$and` is when you need to satisfy multiple criterion for the same field. If the field names are different, it's equivalent to simply using a criteria object (where keys are implicitly and-ed).

Comment: The problem wasn't with my query but somewhere else in my architecture. I have the $and statement because my actual code generates a lot of $or statements among other things, but I might try removing it once I have everything else working, just to see what happens